# How to Increase the AURA Component Width while referred in a screen flow

Tags: aura, screen-flow, lightning-quickaction

I have a aura component which was being used as a Quick Action, but now am trying to use the same component in a screen flow by implementing lightning:availableForFlowScreens interface.

In the flow screen, the component is shrieked and not able to see the full width, by using below code I have solved same issue in a quick action, but is there a way to solve this in a flow screen?

```
<aura:html tag="style">
 .slds-modal__container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 90rem;
 min-width: 30rem;
 }
</aura:html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-modal__container { 
        width : 80% !important; 
        max-width : 80% !important; 
    }
 
    .slds-modal__content {
        height: 100% !important; 
        max-height: 95% !important; 
    }
</aura:html>
```

Comment: thank you very much, this worked perfectly well.

Comment: You're welcome @Rajasekhar